# Power Automate SFTP error: Badgateway - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: sftp, power-automate, ssh-keys

I have a Power Automate workflow which was working successfully until today. I attempted to rename the connector, which automatically wiped all of the information. I re-entered all of the information, but I am running into an SSH key error.

I have a .ppk file which contains both the public and private keys. Using that .ppk file I am able to successfully connect via FileZilla.

I read that Power Automate does not accept .ppk files, so I took the following steps to generate a new RSA private key:

- In PuttyGen, I loaded the .ppk file with the correct passphrase
- In the toolbar I clicked Conversions > Export OpenSSH Key
- This generated a .pem file that looks something like below:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: xxx-xxxx-xxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[key characters]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have also tried using the `Private-Lines` section of the .ppk file surrounded by `BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY`, with a different error (`DER length is '56' and cannot be more than 4 bytes`). That key looks like below:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[copy/paste the private key from the .ppk file]
----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have been using the devtools to track network traffic, so when I go to save the Connection in Power Automate it gives the error `Permission denied (publickey).` The parent error message has a status of 502 with the message `BadGateway`.

I know the key is valid because I am able to connect to it via FileZilla, and the flow was working successfully yesterday. I have seen countless posts online about this same issue, with very little solutions posted. Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Edit: I am including the original .ppk file, with everything sensitive removed.

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-3: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: rsa-key-20220916
Public-Lines: 6
[public key characters]
Key-Derivation: Argon2id
Argon2-Memory: 8192
Argon2-Passes: 13
Argon2-Parallelism: 1
Argon2-Salt: [hex string]
Private-Lines: 14
[private key characters]
Private-MAC: [hex string]
```

Comment: This is the only thing I can suggest checking … “SSH private key (the content of the file should be provided entirely as is, in the multiline format)” … without having all of the information you have (which you never Will or should give us) makes it hard to help.

Comment: Your key is protected/encrypted by a passphrase. I do not know Power Automate. But unless you gave it the passphrase too (in addition to the key) somehow, it won't be able to use your key. Try removing the passphrase from the key.

Comment: I included the original .ppk file, with everything sensitive removed. I believe Power Automate just needs the correct formatting, but I am unsure what that is. Also, the key is passphrase protected but Power Automate has a field for a passphrase entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by following this [YouTube](https://youtu.be/VW6gqVsvOeQ?si=FD0p6WC0YaTZQaqp&t=1130) video. In short, Power Automate only accepts OpenSSH keys, which I stated above. The original .ppk file I used included a passphrase, so I included it in the OpenSSH key generation. However for some reason Power Automate does not like passphrases. Creating an OpenSSH key without a passphrase did the trick. Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.

So in short, follow these steps:

- Import the .ppk file to PuttyGen (and input your passphrase when prompted)
- Remove the passphrase
- Go to Conversions > Export OpenSSH Key
- Use that key in Power Automate, and leave the passphrase field blank